# Convert object to byte[]

Tags: c#, object, arrays, memorystream, binaryformatter

I am trying to convert a retrieved registry value from `object` to `byte[]`. It is stored as `REG_BINARY`. I tried using `BinaryFormatter` with `MemoryStream`. However, it adds overhead information that I do not want. I observed this when I then converted the byte array to a string by performing the function `Convert.ToBase64String(..)`. I am performing these functions because I am testing the storing and retrieval of an encrypted key in the registry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a REG_BINARY then it should already *be* a byte array when you retrieve it... can't you just cast it to `byte[]`?

Alternatively, if you haven't already *verified* that it's REG_BINARY in the code, you may want to use:

```
byte[] binaryData = value as byte[];
if (binaryData == null)
{
    // Handle case where value wasn't found, or wasn't binary data
}
else
{
    // Use binaryData here
}
```

Comment: Ok, yes this is the answer. I have not used C# in a while so obviously I am rusty. Thank you for posting the obvious answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  If it already is a REG_BINARY, all you need to do is cast it:

```
static byte[] GetFoo()
{

  var obj = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software", "foo", null);
  //TODO: Write a better exception for when it isn't found
  if (obj == null) throw new Exception(); 

  var bytearray = obj as byte[];
  //TODO: Write a better exception for when its found but not a REG_BINARY
  if (bytearray == null) throw new Exception(); 

  return bytearray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you converted it using Convert.ToBase64String, you should be able to get it out similarly.

```
string regValueAsString = (string)regValueAsObj;
byte[] buf = Convert.FromBase64String(regValueAsString);
```